# What's the difference between setting cache with {% header %} tag and {% cache %} tag?

Tags: cache

I've came to a cache problem/question on one of my sites when I run a speed test and I failed caching test. I have very little knowledge in this area and I'd like to enhance it.

Documentation for [{% header %}](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/header) tag says that it set a new HTTP header in response and you can tell browser what to do *(for example caching a page)*.

Documentation for [{% cache %}](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/cache) tag say that it will cache a portion of your template.

So what's the difference in setting cache in HTTP header using `{% header %}` tag and `{% cache %}` tag?

Comment: I found [this article](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html) about leveraging browser caching. Is `{% header %}` tag about enabling cache and setting it what to cache for a site?

Comment: Probably worth reading: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/13383/57

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `header` tag sets an HTTP response header, which may be used to (among other things) tell the *browser* that the response content is "cacheable".

The `cache` tag tells Craft to cache the generated HTML on the *server* side (as a file).

Comment: Cache tag is clear to me what it does now. Do I need something else to cache a webpage except the code from documentation about the header tag? That's another question...

Comment: You wouldn't typically set the cache headers in Craft. That's usually a job for your Apache / nginx config.